# Overlapping screens with header in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

In React Navigation, I'm using a stack navigator v5.
For the header, I have created a custom header, and passed it to screenOptions like so:

```
<Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="main"
      screenOptions={{
        header: ({ previous, navigation }) => {
          return (
            <AppHeader
              previous={previous}
              navigation={navigation}
              theme={theme}
            />
          )
        },
      }}
    >
```

For the custom navigator I have used the Appbar component from react-native paper.
Inside that custom header, I have created a component (ListeningIndicator) which, at certain events, expands beyond the headers height. For example:
[header expandable component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDbXj.png)

```
return (
        <Appbar.Header style={{
            backgroundColor: theme.colors.secSurface,
            // height: 50,
            // position: 'absolute',
            // zIndex: 999,
            // elevation: 9999,
            // top: 170
            // borderColor: "red",
            // borderWidth: 1
        }}>
            {previous ? (
                <Appbar.BackAction
                    onPress={navigation.goBack}
                    color={theme.colors.primary}
                />
            ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{ width: "12.5%", alignItems: "center" }}
                    onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                >
                    <DNDIcon audioDeviceState={audioDeviceState} bluetoothPTTServiceState={bluetoothPTTServiceState} theme={theme} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}

            <View
                style={{
                    width: '75%',
                    height: '100%',
                    //position: 'absolute',
                    //top: 20,
                    // height: 100,
                    color: theme.colors.primary,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                   
                }}
            >
                <ListeningIndicator />

            </View>
        </Appbar.Header>
    );
```

The problem I'm facing is, on the area that the component is no longer between the header's height, I no longer have pointer events. I do clearly see the component on top of the screens below the header though.

As you can see in the code above, I have tried working with zIndex and absolute positioning, but the header itself doesn't seem to be able to go "over" the screens.

I'm trying to avoid using the component outside of the header, lets say having the component mounted on screens and then positioning it absolutely, since I don't want to worry about rerenders of the component between screens, or fitting it on the header

Is it possible to overlap the screens with the header, so all pointer events coming from the header are prioritized over the screen's?